# Passing string in stdin

Tags: android, python, subprocess, stdin

I want to create an AVD (Android Virtual Device) through command line in python. For that, I need to pass a string `n` to the stdin. I have tried the following

```
emulator_create = str(subprocess.check_output([android,'create', 'avd', '-n', emulator_name, '-t', target_id, '-b', abi],stdin=PIPE))
emulator_create.communicate("n")
```

but it raises the following error

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/fahim/Android/Sdk/tools/android', 'create', 'avd', '-n', 'samsung_1', '-t', '5', '-b', 'android-tv/x86']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What can I do?

Comment: You should catch the error and check the `output` attribute of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There's something not working with your example. [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) returns the output from the child process you want to execute, **not** a handle to this process. In other words you get a string object (or maybe a bytes object) which you cannot use to manipulate the child process.

Probably what happens is that your script, using `subprocess.check_output()`, will execute the child process and wait until it is finished before continuing. But since you are never able to communicate with it, it will finish with a non-zero return value which will raise the [`subprocess.CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError)

---

Now, using [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) as an example of a command that waits on the standard input to execute something (since I don't have an Android Virtual Device creator installed) you could do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import subprocess

external_command = ['/bin/grep', 'StackOverflow']
input_to_send = '''Almost every body uses Facebook
You can also say that about Google
But you can find an answer on StackOverflow
Even if you're an old programmer
'''

child_process = subprocess.Popen(args=external_command, 
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      universal_newlines=True)
stdout_from_child, stderr_from_child = child_process.communicate(input_to_send)
print "Output from child process:", stdout_from_child
child_process.wait()
```

It will print "Output from child process: But you can find an answer on StackOverflow", which is the output from `grep`.

In this example, I have

1. Used the class [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to create an handle to the child process

   - Setting arguments `stdin` and `stdout` with the value `subprocess.PIPE` to enables us to communicate later on with this process.
2. Used its [`.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method to send a string to its standard input. In the same step, I retrieved its standard output and standard error output.
3. Printed the standard output retrieved in the last step (just so to show that it is actually working)
4. Waited that this child process is finished

In Python 3.5, it's even simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import subprocess

external_command = ['/bin/grep', 'StackOverflow']
input_to_send = '''Almost every body uses Facebook
You can also say that about Google
But you can find an answer on StackOverflow
Even if you're an old programmer
'''

completed_process_result = subprocess.run(args=external_command, 
                                          input=input_to_send,
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          universal_newlines=True)
print("Output from child process:", completed_process_result.stdout)
```

In this example, I have:

- Used the module function [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) to execute the command.

  - The `input` argument is the string we send to the standard input of the child process
  - The return value is used later on to retreive the output of the child process

Now you have to adapt this code to your situation.